# how to automatically restart npm every time i switch branches on git?

Tags: git, npm, nodemon

Every time i switch branches on git, there is a build error. The build disappears if I restart npm. How to automatically restart npm every time i switch branches on git? I tried nodemon, but it restarts way too many times. Is there any other solution that works for this specific situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a specific command after switching between git branches (in your case `npm restart`), you might want to create git alias and execute restart immediately after the checkout. Just add the following to your git config file.

```
[alias]
    npm-checkout = "!res() { git checkout $@ && npm restart; }; res"
```

So from now on instead of using `git checkout` you will use `git npm-checkout` which will switch git branch and restart npm.

============================== Updated ====================================

It will work only if you run `git npm-checkout` from the same terminal. However if you want to restart node which is running in a different terminal, there are a few additional steps. One of the possible solutions is assign an process id to your app, and then kill it using linux `pkill` command. 
`

```
app.js: 
process.title = "processId";
console.log("Sleep for 10 seconds");
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Wake up")
}, 10000);`
```

and inside your package.json

`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "stop": "pkill processId || true"
  }
}
```

`

I hope this helps.

Comment: npm() { git checkout $@ && npm restart }; npm: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: oh yes, there is missing semicolon after npm restart;  so it should look similar to this :    `"!npm() { git checkout $@ && npm restart; }; npm"`

Comment: that gets rid of the `unexpected end of file syntax error` but, it doesn't restart npm. npm is running in a different terminal. need to kill that and then restart it.  if you just do what u wrote, the you get this `error: pathspec 'restart' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: I still didn't find any solution for this problem, except manually quitting `npm` and typing `npm start` everytime i switch branches

Comment: I have updated initial response. It might help to solve your issue.  The right alias is `"!res() { git checkout $@ && npm restart; }; res"` however you still need a few extra steps in order to restart npm properly.